# Sheafs and closed immersion

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $f:X \rightarrow Y$ be a continuous map of topological spaces, such that it is closed immersion. Let $\mathfrak{F}$ and $\mathfrak{G}$ be sheafs on $X$ and $Y$ respectively.
How to show, that canonical morphisms
$$
\mathfrak{G} \rightarrow f_* f^{-1} \mathfrak{G}, \; f^{-1} f_* \mathfrak{F} \rightarrow \mathfrak{F}
$$
are isomorphisms?

Is it true, that taking stalk doesn't commute with direct image, but commutes with inverse image?

Comment: I don't believe the first statement, $f_* f^{-1}$ must have support inside (image in $Y$) of $X$, while your $\mathcal{O}$ can definitely have a larger support to start with. The second canonical morphism should be an isomorphism, and that can be checked at the level of sections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That $f^\ast(f_\ast(\mathcal{F})) \to \mathcal{F}$ is an isomorphism follows from the fact that for a ring $R$, ideal $I$ and $(R/I)$-module $M$, the canonical homomorphism $M_R \otimes_{R} R/I \to M$ is an isomorphism.  The other one is similar.  See [(Stacks project, 24.4.1)](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01QY).

Comment: I think he's working with topological space with a structure sheaf rather than a scheme. (In particular, he's using inverse image sheaf rather than $O_X$-modules.)

Comment: Ah, sorry.  How do we define closed immersions for topological spaces?

Comment: I think it means that $X$ maps homeomorphically to a closed subset of $Y$ through $f$, and that $O_Y \to f_* O_X$ is surjective.

Answer (score 6):

1. Let $Y$ be any topological space, and $ f:X=\lbrace p \rbrace \hookrightarrow Y$, the inclusion of a closed point $p\in X$.
   If $\mathcal G$ is a  sheaf on $Y$, the sheaf $f^{-1}\mathcal G$ is the sheaf on the one-point space $X$ with stalk $\mathcal G_p$ and the sheaf $f_*f^{-1}\mathcal G$ restricted to $ Y\setminus \lbrace p \rbrace $ is zero while $\mathcal G$ will not be zero on $ Y\setminus \lbrace p \rbrace $ in general, so that $$\mathcal G \rightarrow f_* f^{-1} \mathcal G \; $$ will certainly not be an isomorphism.
2. Yes, it is true that if $X\subset Y$ is the inclusion of a subspace (closed or not), then for any sheaf $\mathcal F$ on $X$ the canonical map $$ f^{-1} f_* \mathcal F \rightarrow \mathcal F   $$ is an isomorphism of sheaves.
   It is enough to check that for each $x\in X$ the map of stalks 
   $$ (f^{-1} f_* \mathcal F )_x\rightarrow \mathcal F_x   $$ is bijective.
   Since for  any sheaf $\mathcal G$ on $Y$, we have for all $x\in X$ the equality of stalks $$(f^{-1}\mathcal G)_x=\mathcal G_{f(x)}$$ we have to check that the canonical morphism  $(f_*\mathcal F)_{f(x)}\to \mathcal F_x $ is bijective .
   But this is immediate from the definition $\Gamma(U,f_*\mathcal F)=\Gamma(U\cap X,\mathcal F)$ (for $U$ open in $Y$) if you remember that all open neighbourhoods of $x$ in $X$  are of the form $U\cap X$ for some ope neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ in $Y$.

Comment: In the second example, the morphism $\mathbb{P}^1 \rightarrow \{q\}$ is not a closed immersion.

Comment: Ah yes, you're right: I had forgotten about this condition of yours. I have modified  my answer in order that it take this condition into account. – Georges Elencwajg 1 hour ago

Comment: Since in the second part we do not use that $f(X)$ is closed, am I right that $f^{-1} f_* \mathcal F \rightarrow \mathcal F$ is an isomorphism for any immersion $f$?

Comment: @barto: yes, you are right.

Comment: Thanks. Strange, because I always see this with the assumption that $f$ is a closed or open immersion. I guess there's some more general context where that condition becomes necessary.

Comment: To be precise: the result  is correct whenever $f: X\hookrightarrow Y$ is the inclusion of a  **topological subspace**  $X$  (with induced topology)  into **a topological space** $Y$. I don't know  what immersions of topological spaces are and I'm not saying anything about those. Let me emphasize that my answer concerns **topological spaces**,  and **not** schemes.