# Is the canonical morphism of sheaves $f^{-1}f_*\mathcal F\to \mathcal F$ an isomorphism?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a closed immersion of topological spaces. Let $\mathcal F$ be  a sheaf of rings on $X$. Is the canonical morphism of sheaves $\varphi: f^{-1}f_*\mathcal F\to \mathcal F$ an isomorphism?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Here $f$ is also a closed immersion.

Comment: @Born to be proud. You are right, I misread the question. I have deleted my comment and apologize to you and eloiPrime. Thanks for your vigilance.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg It doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, $\varphi$ is an isomorphism: I showed it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/228781/3217)
However if  $f$ is not assumed to be a closed immersion (=the inclusion of a closed subspace) , the result is no longer true in general.
Here is a counterexample:

Let $X$ be an arbitrary topological space space, take for $\mathcal F$  the sheaf of continuous functions $\mathcal C$ on $X$  and let $Y=\{y\}$ be a point.   Of course $f$ must be the constant map $X\to Y:x\mapsto y$.
Then $f_*\mathcal C= A_Y$, the constant sheaf on $Y$ with (unique!) stalk $A=\mathcal C(X)$.
Hence $f^{-1}f_*\mathcal F=A_X$, the **constant** sheaf on $X$ with fibre $A$.
Since obviously the sheaf $\mathcal C$ is not constant in general, the sheaf morphism $\varphi: f^{-1}f_*\mathcal C=A_X\to \mathcal C$ **cannot** be an isomorphism in general.

Answer (score 0):

$\forall x\in X$, $(f^{-1}f_*\mathcal F)_x\simeq (f_*\mathcal F)_{f(x)}\simeq \mathcal F_x$, so $\varphi$ is an isomorphism. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes it is correct and proved in detail [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/228781/3217)